# convert given foreach statements into a single LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

How to convert given foreach statements into a single LINQ query?

```
foreach (SubsystemBuild img in contentsXMLObj.SubsystemBuilds)
{
    foreach (BuildImage buildImage in build.Images)
    {
        if (buildImage.Name.Equals(img.BuildName) && 
            buildImage.IsOverride == false && 
            img.BaseBuildPath != null)
        {
            buildImage.LocalPath = img.BaseBuildPath;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Since we're not a code-writing service, you're likely to get more help if you show us how _your_ attempt failed.

Comment: When dealing with nested `foreach` you'll want to use `SelectMany` when converting to Linq.  However since this has a side effect you should really still have at least one `foreach`.  In fact I'd say leave it as is.

Comment: @juharr is is not possible to completely replace nested foreach using linq

Comment: Yes you can replace nested `foreach`, but your code has side effects thus you still have to iterate over the Linq query in order to preform the side effect (of setting the `LocalPath`).  I personally do not think this code would benefit from a conversion to Linq.

Comment: There's no reason to convert this code to LINQ format. I'd argue that it's more readable (and easier to maintain) as-is.

Comment: @DanWilson I don't know... took a while, but I was able to get to a linq version at the end of my answer that I think is pretty solid win over the original.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn To each his own, I suppose. 1) I have to use a horizontal scrollbar to read your version 2) My preference would be to split null conditional and null coalescing operators onto separate lines 3) The original version would more easily accept breakpoints for debugging. I appreciate the goal of concise code, but I'll take "naive" code over "clever" code any day because when there's a bug, I want to quickly fix it and move on.

Comment: I'll give you breaking up the ? operators. That helps with the scrolling, too, and I may incorporate it into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get this as a single linq statement. Since you're assigning a change to one of the sequences, you'll still need a `foreach` loop. But you can use linq to re-organize the code.

```
// items in joined are Tuple<BuildImage, string>
var joined = build.Images
     .Where(b => !b.IsOverride)
     .Join( contentsXMLObj.SubsystemBuilds.Where(img => img.BaseBuildPath != null), 
            b => b.Name,
            img => img.BuildName,
            (b, img) => (b, img.BaseBuildPath) );

foreach(var item in joined)
{
   item.Item1.LocalPath = item.Item2;
}
```

Note I still prefer traditional vs query comprehension syntax, but that doesn't mean this isn't linq.

You could do something similar with `SelectMany()`, but neither that version nor this really look any clearer to me, and I have doubts they will run any faster.
What I might do instead is still use the nested loops, but use linq `.Where()` operations to handle the `null` filters at each level:

```
foreach (SubsystemBuild img in contentsXMLObj.SubsystemBuilds.Where(img => img.BaseBuildPath != null))
{
    foreach (BuildImage buildImage in build.Images.Where(b => !b.IsOverride) )
    {
        if (buildImage.Name.Equals(img.BuildName)
        {
            buildImage.LocalPath = img.BaseBuildPath;
        }
    }
}
```

This is a little easier to follow, and has a chance to improve performance by more aggressively culling ineligible items.

You might do better still by pushing the inner filter into it's own list at the beginning, to avoid re-running that filter. This idea is trading a little more memory use to get faster overall execution:

```
var images = build.Images.Where(b => !b.IsOverride).ToList();
foreach (var img in contentsXMLObj.SubsystemBuilds.Where(img => img.BaseBuildPath != null))
{
    foreach (var buildImage in images.Where(b => b.Name.Equals(img.BuildName))
    {
        buildImage.LocalPath = img.BaseBuildPath;
    }
}
```

One more thing to consider is this will set the same field on the same object potentially several times. Depending on the size of each sequence and the logical relationships between them, you *might* do **much** better by inverting them. This will also let us write code where we're sure we never try to assign to the same object more than once:

```
var subbuilds = contentsXMLObj.SubsystemBuilds.Where(img => img.BaseBuildPath is object).ToList();
foreach(var buildImage in build.Images.Where(b =>!b.IsOverride))
{
    var newPath = subbuilds.First(img => buildImage.Name.Equals(img.BuildName))?.BuildPath;
    buildImage.LocalPath = newPath ?? buildImage.LocalPath;
}
```

Now this I like! It's much shorter, and still pretty easy to understand. And it *probably* also performs much better.

But as always, don't take performance assumptions for granted. It's easy to make mistakes there. If performance matters, you need to *measure*.

Comment: Did you mean `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First`?

Comment: I've used `LastOrDefault` to deal to avoid assigning multiple times.

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` would probably be better. `LastOrDefault()` still iterates through all of the results, even when you only want one, while the `First` options can stop the loop after the first match.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i wanted...

```
var subsysBuild = contentsXMLObj.SubsystemBuilds
                                .Where(s => s.BuildName.Equals(BuildImage.Name) && s.BaseBuildPath != null && !BuildImage.IsOverride)
                                .FirstOrDefault();
                    BuildImage.LocalPath = subsysBuild != null ? subsysBuild.BaseBuildPath : BuildImage.LocalPath; 
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my effort.

## Iteration 1

```
//foreach (SubsystemBuild img in contentsXMLObj.SubsystemBuilds)
//{
foreach (BuildImage buildImage in build.Images)
{
    if( buildImage.IsOverride == false && contentsXMLObj.SubsystemBuilds.LastOrDefault( img => buildImage.Name.Equals(img.BuildName) && img.BaseBuildPath != null) is var img && img != null) 
    {
        buildImage.LocalPath = img.BaseBuildPath;
    }
}
//}
```

## Iteration 2a

`ToList()` may be needed for `build.Images.`, if it's not a `List`.

```
//foreach (SubsystemBuild img in contentsXMLObj.SubsystemBuilds)
//{
//  foreach (BuildImage buildImage in build.Images)
//  {
    build.Images.ForEach( buildImage => { 
        if( buildImage.IsOverride == false && contentsXMLObj.SubsystemBuilds.LastOrDefault( img => buildImage.Name.Equals(img.BuildName) && img.BaseBuildPath != null) is var img && img != null) 
        {
            buildImage.LocalPath = img.BaseBuildPath;
        }});
//  }
//}
```

## Iteration 2b

`ToList()` may be needed for `build.Images.`, if it's not a `List`.

```
build.Images.ForEach(buildImage => 
    buildImage.LocalPath = buildImage.IsOverride == false && contentsXMLObj.SubsystemBuilds.LastOrDefault( img => buildImage.Name.Equals(img.BuildName) && img.BaseBuildPath != null) is var img && img != null 
        ? img.BaseBuildPath
        : buildImage.LocalPath);
```